# Should I report this UK road accident to the police?

Tags: driving, officials

I was involved in an accident (in England, A259) this morning, with four vehicles (v1 to v4, v1 in front and me in v2) involved, in line and hit from behind. I was driving the second vehicle from the front. It happened when we slowed in traffic, and the vehicle in front of me (v1) had stopped or almost stopped. I was almost stationary safely short of him, when my car (vehicle 2) was hit from behind and pushed into v1 in front of me. After an obscenity filled pause I and v1 pulled ahead a little and on to the verge. We established that both our vehicles 1 and 2 had suffered no damage beyond a few superficial scratches.

However the van behind me, vehicle 3, I could see had had its front number plate knocked off. The last vehicle 4 now badly damaged at its front end, had been the source of the accident, having run at speed into the back of v3 and shunted us all forward. I did not look at the damage to v3, it was hidden by  the wreckage of v4. Having established everyone ok, I and v1 went on, leaving the drivers of v3 and v4 to sort it out.

Should I have done more, like give them my details or especially should I have informed the police?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel. Try Law.Stackexchange.com for a better response.

Comment: This is covered by Section 170 of the 1988 Road Traffic Act; http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/170

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really appropriate for this site, but...

You **don't** need to report it to the police.

You ***should*** report it to your insurance company, giving as many of the other parties details as possible.

Why? Because all parties have several years in which to lodge a claim against you - if you report it *now*, your insurance company can investigate it with the other parties and come to a "no fault" closure on your account, ending the threat of claims and litigation later on.

I have seen insurance cases where there has been no damage at the scene, but one party has lodged a claim two years later for a new radiator or whatever, and because the person being claimed against failed to report the accident to their insurance company at the time it was almost impossible to fight.

Comment: If anyone is injured, you are required to call the police and remain at the scene until the police arrive.